# passing video_url to html template in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to dispaly video in my html page by passing url as dict to template in django view named as succes

```
def success(request):
    url_video="/media/video1.mp4"

    return render(request,"payment/success.html",{"url_video":url_video})
```

my template code is all clear it has no errors
i am getting this error on command prompt

```
Not Found: /succes/media/video1.mp4
```

I don't understand why i get success/ in front of url i have passed.The video file is in media/video1.mp4 location but it is not getting displayed.let me know any changes i need to make.thanks

**EDIT:**

TEMPLATE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<style> #myHeader { background-color: lightblue; color: black; padding: 40px; text-align: center; } 
</style> 
</head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
<body> 
<h1 id="myHeader">"{{ url_video}}"</h1> <br> 

<video width=""height=""controls> 
    <source src="{{ url_video}}" type="video/mp4"> 
</video> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Show`success.html` template code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/P1rEg4eX this is link to succes.html

Comment: `<meta name="viewport"...` belongs inside `<head>` tag. Are you sure you have the leading slash in `url_video="/media/video1.mp4"`?

Comment: thanks yeah that is my error thanks very much . it worked i  made mistake in using slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a relative path problem.  Make sure you have:

```
url_video="/media/video1.mp4"
```

and not

```
url_video="media/video1.mp4"
```

Without the leading slash, it will try to find in directory of current url